# How to do greater than syntax in a Mongoose.js query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I get a 'greater than' syntax to work for this Mongoose query?

```
var where = {};
where._id = req.wine.id;
where.sameAs = undefined;
where.scoreTotal > 0; //THIS NEEDS TO SET TO DO GREATER THAN 0
where.mode = 'group';
where.deleted = false;
Wine.find(where, callback).populate('user');
```

It keeps crashing my node server.

I'd like to keep this where object syntax instead of doing the inline where object syntax for readability sake. Could I do something like:

```
where.scoreTotal = $gt(0);
```

Comment: Seriously? `where.scoreTotal = { "$gt": 0 }`. Why would you not look at the offical documentation for MongoDB? If you are using it I would expect you to at least read the basic tutorial first ["Query Documents"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks for the guidance. I'm new to MongoDB and was getting my syntax all mixed up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Refer official documentation for clear explanation & complete usage detais :
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Instead of `where.scoreTotal > 0`
Add `"where.scoreTotal" : { $gt : 0}`

Answer (score 35):

You can use query like

```
Person.
  find({
    occupation: /host/,
    'name.last': 'Ghost',
    age: { $gt: 17, $lt: 66 },
    likes: { $in: ['vaporizing', 'talking'] }
  }).
  limit(10).
  sort({ occupation: -1 }).
  select({ name: 1, occupation: 1 }).
  exec(callback);
```

or using query builder

```
Person.
  find({ occupation: /host/ }).
  where('name.last').equals('Ghost').
  where('age').gt(17).lt(66).
  where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking']).
  limit(10).
  sort('-occupation').
  select('name occupation').
  exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator for query that deals with greater than conditions.

Comment: Yes, but how do I use the $gt in this where = {} scenario?

where.scoreTotal = ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$gt` or `$gte`

```
$gt  => Greater than
$gte => Greater than or equal to
```

In Action

```
Document.find({
 scoreTotal: { $gt: 0 } 
})
```

The following list is common operators

```
$eq  => Equal
$ne  => Not equal
$gt  => Greater than
$gte => Greater than or equal to 
$lt  => Less than
$lte => Less than or equal to
$in  => It's clear
$nin => Not in
```

**More information for** [**$in**](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/the-mongoose-in-operator-1015)